# How to make a directive parameter required?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Having developed an Angular directive:

```
<p mydirective="param" [mydirectiveConfig]="{some: keys}">Text</p>
```

how can I enforce the param (attribute value) and another input to be required and make the compiler throw an error should it encounter null?

I want both `param` and presence of `mydirectiveConfig` to be present in the markup.

Comment: in your directive's ngOnint, check for both of those values and throw an error if they do not exist. Or attempt to do somethign with those values, and an error will be thrown if they are undefined.

Comment: Yes, it works in that compiler breaks (due to undefined received by ngModule), although I would expect the error messages to be output into the console, as guidance for the developer

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do? If you want to output an error, than throw it yourself i.e., throw new Error("you must provide a param")

Comment: This is exactly what I am after and what I did, but I never saw this message in the console. The compiler breaks down before the message is emitted.

Comment: Then that means you are trying to use the values somewhere. Otherwise it would not break.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta consider to add your comment as an answer